# CSS3 issue in Chrome/Safari with jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, webkit

[Please see this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QcZdX/4/)
In **Chrome** (version 23) and **Safari**, if you keep clicking the "top" link to move the items to the top, the "top" button will start getting hidden when it shouldn't be.
Since I'm using **CSS3** `first-child/last-child`, I'm expecting only the top and bottom LI's button visibility to be altered.
I noticed if I get rid of the calls to "animate", it works as expected.
This fiddle DOES work in Firefox 17 and IE 9.
Anyone know what's happening here?

Looks like these styles aren't being reapplied correctly:

```
ul#sortable li:first-child a.top { visibility:hidden; }
ul#sortable li:last-child a.bottom { visibility:hidden; }
```

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. It looks like it does work, using Opera 12 and Chromium 18.

Comment: @feeela - on item 3, click top. The on item 2, click top. After the sorting, item 3 is missing the top link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by resetting the position property of the links to relative after the sorting is done.

```
$(this).parent().find('a').css('position','relative');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QcZdX/6/)**